# How to extract the Substring from URL present in JSON response using JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I've the below JSON response received from the HTTP request. I want to extract the parameters from the node "url" present in the JSON response.

```
{"Id":"7S9LyBqyv1e0trKrVuP1OOZGHeg","Url":"https://abcd.com:443/u/custom-response?prov=34545sdf-9013e2e61e66&realmeId=%2Fxxxx","realmeId":"/abcd"}
```

In the above JSON response, i want to retrieve the value of "prov" which is 34545sdf-9013e2e61e66 using JMeter.
Solution Tried: Used Beanshell to read the response.

```
String url = vars.get("successURL");
vars.put("responseURL",url.toString());
responseURL = responseURL.replaceAll(":"," ");
log.info("String URL "+responseURL.toString());
```

Error Message:

```
attempt to resolve method: toString() on undefined variable or class name: responseURL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use complex Beanshell coding, You can do this easily using - [`Regular Expression Extractor`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

Here the example:-

[image]

You can see required value extracted and stored in variable name give in Regular expression extractor:

[image]

To understand try out reg-ex, you can use https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to update this line:

```
responseURL = responseURL.replaceAll(":"," ");
```

to something like:

```
responseURL = vars.get("responseURL").replaceAll(":"," ");
```

However I don't guarantee that it will work because I don't know how do you get this `successURL` variable.

What will work is doing everything in one shot using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language which has [built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html), suggested code:

```
def url = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).Url
def params = org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), 'UTF-8')
params.each { param ->
    log.info(param.getName() + '=' + param.getValue())
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: thanks @Dmitri .. this info is also helpful to handle the URLs present in the response.